# Disable the buttons on runtime

Tags: android

I'm trying to enable a button when I execute a function but it gives me an FC Error:

```
06-22 11:26:25.050: WARN/dalvikvm(688): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688):     at com.es.inicio$1.onDateChanged(inicio.java:58)
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688):     at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:397)
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688):     at android.widget.DatePicker.access$100(DatePicker.java:46)
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688):     at android.widget.DatePicker$1.onChanged(DatePicker.java:100)
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688):     at android.widget.NumberPicker.notifyChange(NumberPicker.java:340)
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688):     at android.widget.NumberPicker.changeCurrent(NumberPicker.java:330)
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688):     at android.widget.NumberPicker$3.onClick(NumberPicker.java:153)
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-22 11:26:25.089: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(688):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
l..........................
```

My code is:

```
    DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener listenerCambiado = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               mYear = year;
               mMonth = monthOfYear;
               mDay = dayOfMonth;
               Log.d("PRUEBA","ENTRAMOS EN LISTENER DEL DATEPCKER");
               //comprobarFecha(mYear,mMonth,mDay);
               if (comprobarFechas(mYear,mMonth,mDay)){
                    btnValidar.setEnabled(true);               
               }else{

                    btnValidar.setEnabled(false);

               }
        }
    };

        The function is:

public boolean comprobarFechas (int ano, int mes, int dia){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (ano > c.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"AÑO INCORRECTO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("PRUEBA","AÑO INCORRECTO");
        return false;
        //btnValidar.setEnabled(false);
    }else if (mes > c.get(Calendar.MONTH) && ano == c.get(Calendar.YEAR)){          
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"MES INCORRECTO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("PRUEBA","MES INCORRECTO");
        return false;
        //btnValidar.setEnabled(false);
    }else {
        Log.d("PRUEBA","ESTA BIEN");
        return true;
        //btnValidar.setText("pulsado");
        //btnValidar.setEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: uf.. mixing spanish code with english.. so uncool.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NullPointerException` that mean u forget to supply `findViewById(R.id.controlid);` to any control try to find out this in your code may this solves this error Happy Coding :):) :- Pragna

Comment: Yes I do: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.inicio);
     
     
     final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        // INFLAR 
  Button btnValidar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnValidar);
  btnValidar.setEnabled(false);
  
  DatePicker calendario=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        calendario.init(mYear,mMonth,mDay,listenerCambiado);
        
        ;
     
        
 }

Answer (score 0):

make sure to initialize `btnValidar` using `findViewById()` before trying to access it.

Comment: Yes I do:public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.inicio);
     
     final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        // INFLAR 
  Button btnValidar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnValidar);
  btnValidar.setEnabled(false);
  
  DatePicker calendario=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        calendario.init(mYear,mMonth,mDay,listenerCambiado);
        
        ;
     
        
 }

Comment: you initialize local variable in `onCreate`. Make it a class member or create a local copy in `onDateChanged` and init it